# Using @Type for Binary data in Hibernate >6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am doing a Spring Boot course written in Spring Boot 2.19, Hibernate 5.3.12 and Java 8.
I am using Java 17, Hibernate 6.1.6 and Spring Boot 3.0.2.

I sorted many things that didn't match, but one problem I can't find the solution to is that :

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
```

is apparently deprecated since Hibernate 6 (I get the error "Cannot resolve method **type**")

However, none of the solutions I found were related to binary data and I couldn't find anything relevant in the docs .. I guess because I'm so new to this area I probably can't see the answer when it hits me!

Based on various sources I tried:

```
@Convert(converter = org.hibernate.type.BinaryConverter.class)
```

```
@Type(BinaryType)
```

IDE does not suggest anything for Binary.. in either of the cases..

I guess I could just download the lower version dependency of hibernate, but I am curious still how does this work in the newest Hibernate version?

Comment: I did, it says 'Cannot resolve symbol' for BinaryConverter

Answer (score 15):

You have not really given enough information here, but *probably* the solution is:

```
@JdbcType(VarbinaryJdbcType.class)
```

or:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARBINARY)
```

Comment: @JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARBINARY)
This worked for me in saving a image bytes to postgres.

Answer (score 0):

`@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")` isn't working in Hibernate 6>

but if you are using for converting in `byte[]` type, you can just delete annotation `@Lob` and use `@JdbcTypeCode(Types.BINARY)`.

Answer (score -3):

Quick update in case anyone else encounters this, it appears Hibernate 6 is taking care of this exact type conversion on its own, without the need for additional settings, so simply getting rid off the attribute:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
```

solved the problem and the project appears to be running fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I had to use Gavin King answer

Comment: Simply deleting the added annotation can be a solution, thanks!
By deleting `@JdbcTypeCode(Types.BINARY)` my UUID attribute is going to be persisted in the right way.

Comment: @ISquared: do you mean delete the whole ANNOTATION @Type?
Or just the attribute "type"?